# ID alternatives for a international student in the USA

Tags: usa, australia, study, passports

I'm moving to USA (Tucson, AZ) for graduate school, and was wondering what identification alternatives I could use where ID is required, as I prefer not carrying around my passport with me.

I have an Australian driver's license - would this let me be eligible for IDP (international driver's permit)?

Comment: Welcome to TSE; do note that questions involving temporary relocation are often better-suited to our sister site, [Expatriates.SE]. At the least, it would be useful to know what your use cases would be. A local bar may have certain requirements, the public library other requirements, and still others your bank or the TSA. Do note that the IDP does not constitute acceptable ID by itself; it is a translation of your driver's license—which should be unnecessary for an Australian.

Comment: As a graduate student, you'll most likely be authorized to work on campus.  As I understand it, this will make you eligible to get a social security number (SSN), and with an SSN you can get an Arizona driver's license.

Comment: And practically speaking, that is what you should do.  You can drive with your Australian license if you're just visiting Arizona as a tourist (and according to [this](https://azmvdservices.com/what-international-visitors-need-to-know-before-driving-in-arizona/) you would not even need an IDP, although it is recommended).  However, as soon as you are a full-time student living and working in Arizona, the state will want you to have an Arizona license, and may not consider your Australian license valid.

Comment: Moreover, your Australian license, with or without IDP, will be useless as identification for any purpose besides driving.  Nobody in the US will accept it as proof of your identity (bars, hotels, doctors, etc, etc).

Comment: You'll probably use your student ID for most things on and around campus.

Comment: @NateEldredge a social security number is not a prerequisite to getting a driver's license.  Can you imagine if all these nonimmigrant dependents were ineligible to drive as well as ineligible to work?  It would be unsustainable.

Comment: @phoog: I didn't say an SSN was necessary, only that it was sufficient :-)  But I'm looking at https://www.azdot.gov/motor-vehicles/NewtoAZ/obtaining-a-license and https://www.azdot.gov/motor-vehicles/driver-services/arizona-travel-id/identification-requirements which say explicitly that an SSN is required, and don't mention any exceptions.  I would not be surprised if exceptions exist, so if you know where they're documented, please share.

Comment: @NateEldredge indeed.  Arizona seems to be a very confused place.  They have a law prohibiting the state from participating in Real ID and another one requiring it to do so, although not mentioning the program by name.  The law does seem to lack exceptions to the requirement.  It's entirely possible that they have in a fit of anti-immigrant fervor neglected to account for the fact that there will be legal residents of Arizona who are not eligible to obtain social security numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is to get a State ID. This can be easily done at a local MVD.

Another option would be to get a Driver License. Since you're from Australia*, you will need to get a car (either from a friend or rented) and take a computer and road test.

For either option, I recommend getting an ID valid for Federal Identification (air travel).

You will need the following documents for all options above:

- Passport with Visa
- I-20
- I-94
- Mail with your name and current address (for travel ID only)

Please wait at least 1 week after arriving to the US to apply. It takes some time for SEVIS to update. Plus, your adviser needs to check you in the system.

In regards to the need of a SSN, when I got my license a few years ago SSN was not needed. However, it seems that now the SSN is mandatory. If so, you have 2 options: Ask the DSO to issue you a SSN or provide the DMV with a Form SSA-L676, “Refusal to Process SSN Application.” secure.ssa.gov/apps10/poms.nsf/lnx/0100299020

*Check the list of countries with reciprocity here: https://www.azdot.gov/motor-vehicles/driver-services/Tests_Manuals_and_Driving_Schools/foreign-reciprocity

Comment: "in the state of Arizona you DO NOT need a SSN to get a State ID or Driver License." I believe that is true in every state if you are in a nonimmigrant status that is not eligible to get an SSN.

Comment: @user102008 That is my thought as well. But since every state has their own requirements, I'm not sure about the other ones.

Comment: The SSN requirements are mostly motivated by Real ID and therefore basically the same everywhere as far as I've seen.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the statement that you do not need an SSN for a driver's license?  I don't doubt you, but https://www.azdot.gov/motor-vehicles/NewtoAZ/obtaining-a-license says flatly that "you are required [...] to provide your social security number".

Comment: I am speaking out of my own experience. When I first got my license I didn't have a SSN. They didn't even ask for one. That might have changed however. If so, you have 2 options: Ask the DSO to issue a SSN or provide the DMV with a Form SSA-L676, “Refusal to Process SSN Application.” https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/poms.nsf/lnx/0100299020 I edited my response to reflect the fact that they might ask for SSN now.

Comment: @IanDantas was that before Real ID?  The current Arizona DMV pages do not seem to mention form SSA-L676 as an acceptable substitute for a social security number.

Comment: @phoog I got my license in 2014. I don't remember if Real ID was already a thing back then. The DMV website doesnt but the DHS does. Here it is: https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/obtaining-a-social-security-number

Comment: @IanDantas if Arizona doesn't recognize the SSA-L676 as an acceptable substitute for a social security number, I don't think DHS can require them to do so.  (And if they *do* accept it, then they should change their website to say so.)  As to Real ID, Arizona has a law on the books to prohibit the state from participating, and another that requires it to participate.  I do not know when the second law was passed, but I expect it's almost certainly after 2014.  So Real ID related regulations would not have been in place at the time.